# Like operator in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, sql-like, nosql

In SQL, we have an option to specify the LIKE operator in the where clause. Is there something like that in Cassandra? I am building a search feature for my site. All the data resides on Cassandra. So, it would be easier to search for keywords with LIKE operator.

Answer (score 3):

No.You dont have such feature in cassandra. You gotto create a search engine on the data that is stored in cassandra to index the entries in cassandra may be. Cassandra serves as a container to hold your data and does not provide such features like full text search yet(I doubt if they will really as the storage is across SSTables).

Answer (score 2):

If you need search capabilities on cassandra data, look no further than DSE:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html